# sharing services missing in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` for sharing and mailing in my project.

But only mailing service and message service is shown but not facebook, twitter and other services.

```
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: shareUrl, nil];
```

//code for displaying  `UIActivityviewController`

```
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.captechconsulting.com"];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;


[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

**os: ios7**

Does it depend on iphone settings?
I have enabled permissions and i tried it but the result is same....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add account in your device setting,

**`Setting > Facebook

Setting > Twitter`**

Set it and than try,

```
NSURL *shareUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.captechconsulting.com"];
NSArray *activityItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: shareUrl, nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

If you share image also than related activity will display.